# is there any way to render the element in the react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
return (
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ 
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<DeliveryPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/food" element={<Menu />}></Route>
          </Routes>  
        </div>
      } />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

Problem with the `react-router-dom` is that I am not able to render the `Menu` or `"/food"` part. I tried conditional rendering also but not working properly.

GitHub link - https://github.com/priyanshu2k3/swigato

I am expecting that the `<Navbar />` should be render all time except the `<Signup />` page.

Answer (score 0):

The root route is rendering descendent routes, so the parent should specify an appended `"*"` splat to allow matching all the sub-routes as well.

```
<div>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/*" // <-- allow sub-routes to match
      element={(
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<DeliveryPage />} />
            <Route path="/food" element={<Menu />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      )}
    />
    <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

An alternative is to convert the root `"/"` route into a layout route and render nested routes.

Example:

```
<div>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      element={(
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
        </div>
      )}
    >
      <Route path="/" element={<DeliveryPage />} />
      <Route path="/food" element={<Menu />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</div>
```